# C# Swi-Prolog: how to consult external prolog file in C#?

Tags: c#, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

So far I am able to communicate with prolog with sample code available at prolog website. 
But when I am trying to extract result from my prolog file it does not get the file and ended without any error.
Well the sample code I tested is as below:

```
if (!PlEngine.IsInitialized)
{
  String[] param = { "-q" };  // suppressing informational and banner messages
  PlEngine.Initialize(param);
  PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(martin, inka))");
  PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, gloria))");
  PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, melanie))");
  PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, ayala))");
  using (PlQuery q = new PlQuery("father(P, C), atomic_list_concat([P,' is_father_of ',C], L)"))
  {
  foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
         Console.WriteLine(v["L"].ToString());
  Console.WriteLine("all child's from uwe:");
  q.Variables["P"].Unify("uwe");
  foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
        Console.WriteLine(v["C"].ToString());
  }
  PlEngine.PlCleanup();
  Console.WriteLine("finshed!");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the code I am trying to use is as, my prolog file "OT.pl" is placed in swi-prolog folder:

```
 String[] param = { "-q", "-f", @"OT.pl" };

        if (!PlEngine.IsInitialized)
        {
            try
            {
                PlEngine.Initialize(param);
                PlQuery carrega = new PlQuery("carrega('OT.bd')");
                carrega.NextSolution();
                PlQuery listQuery= new PlQuery("list(X)");
                foreach (PlQueryVariables v in listQuery.SolutionVariables)
                    listBox1.Items.Add(v["X"].ToString());

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure: " + ex.Message);
                // return;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Kindly ignore any indentation mistakes. Thank you in advance.